# How do I pass the result of fetch() function to the React context value, not the default value that I set for the hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have been struggling with this one for some time, and still could not figure this out.
What I am trying to achieve is:

1. fetch the items from the endpoint
2. update the state with the new values
3. Pass this data as context so that i can use it globally on the site.

Everything works well, except for the updating part: the values inside the hook are updated, but context value in the other components is being fetched before the state is updated with the `fetch()` data, so it returns the default state value (empty array, or whatever i put there).

I want the data to arrive updated, or update later in the process, but I do not know why `onComponentUpdated()` hooks or something similar.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My code:

Context provider component, where I fetch the data:

```
function ContextProvider({ children }) {
let [data, setData] = useState([]);
   useEffect(() => {
  fetch("https://mysurl.com")
  .then((newData) => newData.json())
  .then((images) => {
    setData(images.items);
  });
  }, []);
const setNewTheme = () => {
setTheme(
  currTheme.name == "light" ? context.themes.dark : context.themes.light
  );
 };

return (
  <GlobalContext.Provider
    value={{ theme: currTheme, updateTheme: setNewTheme, allProducts: data }}
  >
  {children}
  </GlobalContext.Provider>
 );
 }
```

Context consumer component where I want to use the data:

```
function GridGallery({ gridTitle, sectionTitle, category }) {
  const context = useContext(GlobalContext);
  let data = context.allProducts;
  console.log(data)
}
```

Comment: You have to introduce state in GridGallery and update that state in an effect. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60697733/react-context-not-updating

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure how it is going to help me. I already have states in my context provider function, and I pass the data and setData state parameters to the context receiver. But it still does not help, the state is not getting updated

Comment: It also works for all the other components except the landing page, for some reason....

Comment: Here is the issue. When context is updated with the fetched data, the component "using" that context through hooks don't re-render. You can check out the documentation on lifecycle of a component to understand when a component re-renders.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the note regarding using state. I found the solution, and it was not about the Sate, but rather the fact that I was creating a context and fetching the data in the same component. Creating an intermediate AppWrapper component and fetching data there works like a charm. Thanks!